# Can variables from a php page accessed from 2nd php page if 2nd php page is loaded in iframe from first

Tags: php, iframe

I have 2 php pages.From 1st php page (say 1.php) i print an iframe (obviously using html) & keep its source as 2nd php page (say 2.php) , so my question is wether i can use variables initialized in 1.php from 2.php ?
Like in 1.php i have a variable $name then can i use value of $name from 2.php itself ?
If not then what should be alternative better than sessions (i am using free server!) .

Comment: Please if you can share your code with us so people can help you. and be more specific about your question.

Comment: @DevangRathod : I thought given data in question was apt (2 answers already!) & giving the code will confuse you even more , i simplified it as code is long , complex & clumsy :)

Answer (score 1):

No,

Think about the sequence of events that leads to the page being rendered:

1. 1.php is requested
2. 1.php executes, generating an iframe
3. The iframe is returned to the browser, pointing to 2.php
4. 2.php is requested
5. 2.php executes, generating HTML
6. The output of 2.php is returned to the browser

1.php is finished executing (and all its variables forgotten about) before the browser even knows it wants 2.php.

You can pass variables to 2.php using a query string in the iframe's URL, like `example.com/2.php?var1=val1&var2=val2`.

On the other hand, I think you should re-think how you're building the website. You could, for example, use a `<div>` with `overflow: scroll` in place of an iframe so that there doesn't need to be a second request. You might also consider using `$_SESSION` to keep track of some user data.

Comment: Wont passing data via get will be higly insecure , subject to injections of various forms ? & sensitive data just cant be passed :)
I was avoiding sessions because i will host on free server so using lots of sessions will lessen nos of days i can host (sessions will eat bandwith allotted to me very fast i suppose) :)

Comment: You need to take care to escape the data coming in through query strings. If the data is sensitive then the connection should be encrypted. Sessions won't eat lots of bandwidth.

Comment: sessions wont eat lots of bandwidth ?
I had experimented in my last site , with almost every vital mechanism using sessions and my 10 Gb bandwith was over in just 10 to 20 days and there wasnt much traffic to do so ?

Comment: It depends what you put in the session, but they work by either storing cookies on the client or by propagating a UID in the url. The actual data is stored on the server. It won't eat any more bandwidth than setting the cookies or propagating the UID manually

Comment: Okay , just a vote up , will wait for more solution avoiding session :)

Comment: Thank you for the upvote, but I hope by reading my summary of how the pages are executed you understand why your options are fairly limited. Any information you pass to 2.php has to be routed through the browser in some way, either in the URL of the iframe or by some other means. The best solution would be a redesign of your system, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that variable in that url of that iframe and then you can access that in iframe page - **page.php?var1=value1**

Eg:

```
echo "<iframe src='sitename.com.au/directory/app/pagename.cfm?var1='$val'
        width='100%' scrolling='vertical'></iframe>";
```

Comment: Will not this mechanism prone to various injections ? And sensitive data just cant be passed !